# docker build failed. unable to find image with digest

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

trying to build an image an error occurs

```
Step 16/37 : FROM $IMAGE_PHP as base-backend
 ---> 5fc947f8be08
Step 17/37 : ARG UID
unable to find image "sha256:bafb075f25add74a30374cd88b7ab89e39f2931d6e22e64db6fa75d9bf7ee57e"
```

All required images are pulled. IMAGE_PHP has a different digest.
I don’t understand why docker is looking for an image after the ARG directive.

Answer (score 3):

"--no-cache" solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `docker builder prune` or `docker builder prune --all` to resolve this issue.

More details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405761/6843123